# Does the list object as argument value of an array object occupy memory in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, list, memory

An `array.array` object has a smaller memory footprint than a `list` object in Python. Is it still memory-efficient when you create the `array.array` like below?

```
from array import array
array('l', [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

We're still creating a list object there (as argument value) to create that array. Doesn't that make an array not worth using?

**Update**: It looks like I should reconsider the claim that arrays occupy less space than lists. It seems their behaviour differs across different Python versions:

```
Python 3.5.2 
>>> import array, sys
>>> mylist = [1, 2, 3]
>>> myarray = array.array('i', [1, 2, 3])
>>> sys.getsizeof(mylist)
44
>>> sys.getsizeof(myarray)
44

Python 3.6.3 
>>> import array, sys
>>> mylist = [1, 2, 3]
>>> myarray = array.array('i', [1, 2, 3])
>>> sys.getsizeof(mylist)
88
>>> sys.getsizeof(myarray)
76
```

However, my original question still remains (for Python 3.6). `myarray` used a list to be constructed. How is using an array more memory-efficient?

Comment: While doesn't mention memory explicitly, python.org refers to them as efficient: https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html but I have read it on many other posts that arrays occupy less memory than lists.

Comment: The memory overhead of lists compared to arrays is diminishing as soon as the collections contain a significant amount of entries. for example: 12345 intergers per collection and you save an astounding 0.016% memory by using arrays instead of lists ... so i wouldn't sweat it ;>

Comment: @Exho when you check the **list** size you need to do `sys.getsizeof([1,2,3,4,5])` and not `sys.getsizeof(['l', [1,2,3,4,5]])`

Comment: The list you used to create the array can be immediately garbage-collected afterwards, so its memory use is only momentary.  And `sys.getsizeof()` is measuring two different things here - for arrays, it's the entire object; for lists, it's the list of references only, and does not include the size of the individual elements.

Comment: A list object is created, but as it is anonymous, it is eligible for garbage collection once `array` has finished with it.

Answer (score 1):

`sys.getsizeof` is not recursive. So it shows you, how much is list taking in memory. But not list's contents. Try this:

```
mylist = [ 5000, 5001, 5002 ]
sys.getsizeof(mylist) + sum(sys.getsizeof(q) for q in mylist)
```

outputs `172`.

`array.array` is certainly using less memory, it also packs densier, so it's more cache friendly.

In your example also list is used to create `array.array` and then immediately destroyed. So no big issue here.

Answer (score 0):

By using `array.array` you are storing adjacent C-like primitive values, instead of objects. If the arrays are so big that the size of the initializer list worries you, use an iterator for the initializer. That should reduce memory usage to a single element during array initialization.